# Unexpected token mailTransport firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
'use strict';

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "myemailid@gmail.com",
    pass: "dssacdas324g",
  },
});

// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = 'Cloud Storage for Firebase quickstart';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendOrdEmail = functions.database.ref('/shop_orders/{uid}/{pushid}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

const mailOptions = {
    from: `app name <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: "myvendor@gmail.com",
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to app name!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey aisha! Welcome to app name. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log('New welcome email sent to:', "myvendor@gmail.com");

return 200; 

});
```

**Error**

> sudo firebase deploy --only functions
>
> === Deploying to 'projectname'...
>
> i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
>   run lint
>
> > functions@ lint /project/mydir/functions
> >     eslint .
>
> /project/mydir/functions/index.js   34:9  error  Parsing
>   error: Unexpected token mailTransport
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! functions@ lint:
>   `eslint .` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   functions@ lint script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/midhilaj/.npm/_logs/2019-03-25T08_59_43_803Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `sendOrdEmail` function, you're attempting to use the keyword `await`, but the function isn't declaring as `async`.

You'll want to change the function define line as:

```
exports.sendOrdEmail = functions.database.ref('/shop_orders/{uid}/{pushid}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

You'll also need to make sure you're using the NodeJS 8 runtime to support this keyword.

Comment: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c1sm5346582itd.23 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1509:34)
    at SMTPConnection._respon

Comment: SMTP server host is smtp.gmail.com